# How to POST HTTP data into a 'disabled' input field in HTTP form?

Tags: firefox, browser, html, http, javascript

I need to post data into a box that is showed to me but I am unable to click on it. After inspecting the element in Firefox, I noticed that the input field says 'disabled'=disabled in the tags and then researched how to post in disabled fields.

I ended up saving a copy of the webpage on my local machine and edited the HTML to remove the 'disabled' part and now I was able to enter data in the form but it does not seem to post the data as I keep being redirected back to the same page.

I need to be logged in to post the data or even view the page. Here's the page: https://thisislegal.com/challenge/bonus/2

Like I said, one needs to be logged in to see the POST form. Why am I not able to post the data after saving the HTML page, removing the 'disabled' tag and sending the request?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue using a local proxy to intercept the post request from my browser going to the web server. Then I added the extra parameter in the request (the one that was disabled) and set its value. The server responded as it should have.